# Azure devops test database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, devops

### Goal

I would like to have a solution, that among other things includes an SQL Server Database Project and a Unit Test Project. (+ integration test project?)

That solution is going to be source controlled by a git repository on azure devops, and ideally I would like to have a pipeline that starts a LocalDB (mssqllocaldb) database, runs the script/datpac of the database project, to get it up to speed, and then runs the unit tests that should be able to access to newly created database on the local server.

### What I've got so far

The test I'm attempting is fairly simple: (currently using dapper, which along with the connection string will be moved to the api project as soon as I can get this test working):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDBConnection()
{
    var connString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=custom_db_name_here;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        var result = connection.Query<int>(sql: "select 1", commandType: CommandType.Text);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count(), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.FirstOrDefault(), 1);
    }
}
```

I don't have a lot of experience with devops, this is the yaml file azure devops generated and I added the `start mssqllocaldb` task.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'start mssqllocaldb'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb'

# Publish probably goes here, not sure how though?

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

### Problem

I'm not sure how to create the new database, add all the structures (tables, procedures etc.) and data.

Comment: I might have an answer to your question, but wanted just to be sure is a .net core or .net framework and which version.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi .net framework, it's a new project, so probably 4.8 but not sure yet

Comment: If you're interested in using docker to do something similar, check out this Tim Corey video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yj69cWEG_Yo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use FluentMigrator (alternative to the dacpac approach)

Since you're using dapper, I would recommend that you use [FluentMigrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/index.html) to manage your migrations. This will come in handy as you manage migrations over time in your long running environments, such as prod.

There are two approaches you could take with to scaffold and seed your database for your tests. These two options are really just the two ways you can apply your migrations with FluentMigrator, in-process and out-of-process.

#### Option 1: As part of the test initialisation, in-process (My personal preference)

It appears that you're using the MSTest framework, so you would put in your  `[AssemblyInitialize]` code which runs the migration scripts, and seeds any data. Since the data you're seeding for tests is not intended to be seeded into prod, I would keep this separate to the migration scripts. FluentMigrator gives you the ability to run the migrations in-process (i.e. from your C# code). You can find details in the [FluentMigrator quickstart guide](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-in-process)

Using this approach, your pipeline will not need to change. Another advantage of this is that any developers wanting to scaffold their local db can simply run the test suite after starting their local db.

In my experience, even though I would use this to scaffold the database for tests, I had still used the out-of-process approach for applying the migrations to long running environments.

#### Option 2: As a separate task in your pipeline, out-of-process

This is another option that you can find in the [FluentMigrator quickstart guide](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-in-process). With this option, you'd create a task after starting LocalDB to run the migrations. I don't like this approach because when you're developing locally, you will have to know when to apply migrations by running the command, which is tedious.

## Use SqlPackage (dacpac approach)

[Azure Hosted Agents provide SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-pipelines?view=sql-server-ver16) by default, once you have built your `.dacpac` file, add the following task to your pipeline, making sure to update the path/name of your produced dacpac

```yaml
- script: SqlPackage /Action:Import /SourceFile:"$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\dbproject\bin
debug\project.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=devdb; Integrated Security=true;"
  workingDirectory: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\
  displayName: 'Import dacpac'
```

Comment: I have never used an sql scaffolding framework with .net. How well does this work with more complicated objects, like indices, procedures, jobs, functions etc?

Comment: With FluentMigrator, you can still write .sql scripts to change the schema of your db, add indexes etc., the library just handles figuring out which scripts have been already been run, and which need to be run. Plus it has other features like handling rollbacks. Once you have code running in production, I couldn't imagine not using something like FluentMigrator. If you have other experience, I'd love to hear :)

Comment: I'm not a fan of using scaffolding and migrating for databases, since it's either going to be a fairly limited schema or it's going to be a lot harder to review and maintain it. I've been looking into a way to deploy the dacpac from a `[AssemblyInitialize]` method, since I can't figure out how to do it directly from the pipeline.

Comment: If you want to go with the dacpac approach, I don't think deploying via the test startup is the most appropriate. What is the artifact that defines your database included in your source control? Is it a script or a dacpac file? It sounds like you will need to use a cli tool such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I've tried that, sqlpackage isnt installed on the azure devops hosts.
I think both the script and the dacpac are on .gitignore, they get generated on build from the db project, although I'm not sure how to cleanly deploy it without having a weird relative path like `"../../dbproject/bin/debug/project.dacpac"`.

Comment: It appears that SqlPackage is provided by Azure Hosted Agents by default, the syntax looks like it would be something in my updated answer; Though I haven't used either .dacpac or SqlPackage before, but I hope it helps you find an answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out in the end, I had forgotten that PowerShell needs `.\Name.exe` format to run executables, otherwise it can't find them. I also had to change `/Action:Import` to `/Action:Publish`, since apparently `import` expects a `.bacpac` file. Also had to change `v11` to `mssqllocaldb`. I added an answer containing all the changes I had to make, but I'm still probably going to accept your answer, just not yet, since the last couple of days are when the bounties get the most traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer just so that the end result I went with is included here. The credit should go to [Aaron Zhong and his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272901/azure-devops-test-database/76293654#76293654).

I added an after build event that copies the created `.dacpac` to the root directory of the solution, so that it's easier to access it later. (Also had to add the `.dacpac` to `.gitignore`)

```xml
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).dacpac" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)" ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
```

The final `.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Start SQL server'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Deploy DB dacpac'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '.\SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\$(DBNAME).dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=$(DBNAME); Integrated Security=true;"'
    workingDirectory: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I used an environment variable (`$(DBNAME)`) for the database and the `.dacpac` file (they have the same name, so I only had to create 1 variable for both).

If you want to copy this solution the only thing you should have to change is the environment variable and possibly the trigger branch on the top of the `.yml` file.

I decided not to go with the scaffolding + migration approach, since although it pairs better with git, it feels a lot harder to read and maintain compared to a normal SQL schema.